# Recognize special characters ANTLR4

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I'm fairly new to Antlr and I have a requirement where I need to parse characters like ÿ, ä, ë, û etc using Antlr and the lexer rule that I've written is

```
SPECIAL_CHARATERS : 'ÿ' | 'ä' | 'ë' | 'ö' | 'û' ;
```

and used it in parser rule like

```
special: SPECIAL_CHARATERS? ;
```

but it is not recognizing the characters and throwing

```
line 1:10 token recognition error at: 'ÿ'
```

Is there any way I can parse these characters?

Edit1:
I'm trying to parse a string that contains these special characters and As we know Java String is internally always encoded in UTF-16 how can I parse these characters? (the question that was asked before(marked this as duplicate of) is parsing an input File, not a string)

Comment: If the duplicate link does not work for you, then state why and someone can reopen this question for you.

Comment: And make sure to include a [mcve]. And also consider using unicode escapes in your grammar instead.